# How to subscribe to multiple Redis channels in the same function?

Tags: haskell, redis

Running Redis 3.2.1 and the latest Hedis library, I have the following publisher program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Database.Redis
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.ByteString as BS
import System.Posix.Process
import Data.String.Conv

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
  runRedis conn run

run = do
    liftIO $ threadDelay $ 1000 * 1000
    pid <- liftIO getProcessID
    publish "chan1" (toS $ show pid)
    publish "chan2" (toS $ show pid)
    liftIO $ Prelude.putStrLn "\n\n%%%%%%%\n\nnext\n\n%%%%%%%%\n\n"
    run
```

The subscriber looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Database.Redis

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
  runRedis conn $ do
    pubSub (subscribe ["chan1"]) $ \msg -> do
      putStrLn $ "chan1 " ++ show (msgChannel msg) ++ ": " ++ show (msgMessage msg)
      return mempty
    pubSub (subscribe ["chan2"]) $ \msg -> do
      putStrLn $ "chan2" ++ show (msgChannel msg) ++ ": " ++ show (msgMessage msg)
      return mempty
```

The output is:

```
%%%%%%%

next

%%%%%%%%

chan1 "chan1": "21542"

%%%%%%%

next

%%%%%%%%

chan1 "chan1": "21542"

%%%%%%%

next

%%%%%%%%

chan1 "chan1": "21542"

%%%%%%%

next

%%%%%%%%
```

Now, it would appear that as soon as the subscriber reads the first channel, messages sent to the second channel are not read. Put another way, it would appear that the command to subscribe to `chan2` is simply ignored.

For completeness, here's my `Cabal` file:

```
name:                pub-sub-exp
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Simple project template from stack
description:         Please see README.md
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/pub-sub-exp#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2016 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable pub
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Pub.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       hedis,
                       mtl,
                       bytestring,
                       unix,
                       string-conv

executable sub
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Sub.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       hedis,
                       mtl,
                       bytestring
```

I am using `stack-lts-6.6`.

---

For clarification, I would like the subscriber to indicate that messages were sent to both channel 1 and 2.

Is this a well-known property of Redis? Am I missing some Haskell gotcha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to both channels in a single action.

```
pubSub (subscribe ["chan1", "chan2"]) $ \msg -> do
```

Hedis isn't reaching your second call to `pubSub`. You can see from [`pubSub`'s definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.9.1/docs/src/Database-Redis-PubSub.html#pubSub) that unless the subscription count and pending messages are both drained the function will not return. Notice also that there is no forking or other method of enabling concurrency.

Comment: Hmm... So this is an undocumented feature of the `hedis` implementation? Or is it something it inherits from `redis`?

Comment: A little of column A, a little of column B. It actually is documented (just not in the `pubSub` function itself), and is intentional behavior given Redis' PubSub semantics. Check out the **Enforced Pub/Sub semantics** section in the description of the [`hedis` package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis).

Comment: Although @ErikR's answer is correct -- in that it explains using the source code why this behaviour is so -- this answer actually explains the behaviour at a higher level, and gives a code snippet to get the desired result. So I shall accept this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `pubSub` action blocks until its action removes all subscriptions.

You can see how this works by looking at the pubSub test in the hedis test suite:

https://github.com/informatikr/hedis/blob/e86143db2d4e76fe85340c78c01da7bc3722ae5a/test/Test.hs#L385

A trace of what goes on in the test:

- A thread is forked to send two events one second apart - first a `chan1` event and then a `chan2` event
- The first `pubSub` establishes a listener for `chan1` events.
- When it receives the `chan1` event it changes its subscription to a pattern subscription.
- When the `chan2` event arrives it cancels all subscriptions. Then "control" goes to the next pubSub action.
- The second pubSub action has no subscriptions so it exits immediately.

Comment: hey i added an example for anyone who needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146582/stackexchange-redis-how-to-subscribe-to-multiple-channels/55281008#

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern subscription http://redis.io/commands/psubscribe

```
psubscribe chan*
```

Hope this helps