# StackExchange.Redis how to subscribe to multiple channels

Tags: c#, redis

How can i subscribe to multiple channels? As far as i understand Channel class, which needs to be passed to Subscribe method, supports pattern or single channel subscription. Is it possible to subscribe to multiple channels in one command?

Example:
A client is publishing on 3 different channels: 'ChannelA', 'ChannelB' and 'ChannelC'. How can i subscribe to these channels in one command? I know i can use pattern like 'Channel*' but, what if those channels cannot be described by a single pattern? Subscribing to "ChannelA, ChannelB, ChannelC" does not seem to work - i cannot get any message from the ChannelMessageQueue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PSUBSCRIBE](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe):

`PSUBSCRIBE Channel*`

That should listen to any channel starting with "Channel".

Or you can use [SUBSCRIBE](https://redis.io/commands/subscribe) with multiple channels:

`SUBSCRIBE ChannelA ChannelB ChannelMessageQueue`

Answer (score 0):

psubscribe has been used under IRedisSubscription interface then we can use 
**subscription.SubscribeToChannelsMatching** in c# just give it the pattern as according your need like this line

**subscription.SubscribeToChannelsMatching(_config.ActiveChannelName);**

my sample usage for merging messages to mongodb:

```
public void SubScribeChannel()
{
    string channelName = _config.ActiveChannelName;

    using (var redisConsumer = new RedisClient(_config.SingleHost))
    using (var subscription = redisConsumer.CreateSubscription())
    {
        subscription.OnSubscribe = channel =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Subscribed to '{0}'", channel));
        };
        subscription.OnUnSubscribe = channel =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("UnSubscribed from '{0}'", channel));
        };
        subscription.OnMessage = async (channel, msg) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Received '{0}' from channel '{1}'", msg, channel));
            List<Document> documents = Transformer.Deserialize<List<Document>>(msg);
            await MergeToMongoDb(documents, channelName);
        };

        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("SubscribeToChannels: '{0}'", channelName));
            //subscription.SubscribeToChannels(channelName);
            subscription.SubscribeToChannelsMatching(_config.ActiveChannelName);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("EOF");
}
```

ActiveChannelName's value is a pattern like "TestChannel*"